# How "_" works in python files?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, nameerror

I tried to use "_" in python command line and it's working as well.

```
In [1]: 1234
Out[1]: 1234

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 1234

In [3]: print _
1234

In [4]: 'aaaaa'
Out[4]: 'aaaaa'

In [5]: print _
aaaaa

In [6]:
```

but there is a problem when i using this in a python file.
content of file:

```
'aaaa'
print _
```

returned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\somefolder\f.py", line 2, in <module>
    print _
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

what's the problem ? how I can fix it ? is there anything to replace with "_" and do the same work ?

Comment: Related [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163)

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you.